# Does this 'Belousov-Zhabotinsky Reaction' kit contain the correct reagents?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox, color

I want to run the Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction as a demonstration. As far as I'm aware, you need sodium bromate, sodium bromide, water to $\pu{100 ml}$, malonic acid, phenanthroline and ferrous complex.  This is the recipe that I know, but I can't get hold of the right ingredients.

I found this kit entitled ['Belousov-Zhabotinsky Reaction'](http://global.rakuten.com/en/store/buneidonp/item/924926/) for £15.00. I am not sure it has the right ingredients:

> Kit contents: Iodine sodium, malonic acid, Sulfamic Acid, sodium thiosulfate
>   Manganese sulfate, starch solution, cups 5 pieces, chemicals, racks etc.

Does this kit have the right ingredients for the Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction?

Answer (score 1):

**No, it doesn't, at least not strictly.**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction) (emphasis added):

> One of the most common variations on this reaction uses malonic acid $(\ce{CH2(CO2H)2})$ as the acid and potassium bromate $(\ce{KBrO3})$ as the source of bromine. The overall equation is:
>
> $$ \ce{3CH2(CO2H)2 + 4BrO3− → 4Br− + 9CO2 + 6H2O} $$
>
> [ $\ldots$ ]
>
> Many variants of the reaction exist. **The only key chemical is the bromate oxidizer.**

The kit doesn't contain any bromide or bromate, so by definition it will not allow demonstration of a Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction.

---

**However:** It does appear that the kit ***may*** allow demonstration of an [iodine clock reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction):

> #### Hydrogen peroxide variation
>
> This reaction starts from a solution of hydrogen peroxide with sulfuric acid. To this is added a solution containing potassium iodide, sodium thiosulfate, and starch.

The ingredients are not a perfect match, and actually appear to be something of a mishmash between the iodine clock reaction and the Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction, but they're in the right ballpark. Metal ions and their oxides are [well known](https://www.google.com/search?q=metal%20catalysis%20of%20hydrogen%20peroxide%20decomposition&oq=metal%20catalysis%20of%20hydrogen%20peroxide%20decomposition&aqs=chrome..69i57.7659j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as catalysts for hydrogen peroxide decomposition, and "Sulfamic acid" could be a typo that was supposed to be "sulfuric acid".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfamic_acid Close enough in terms of properties, I guess.

Comment: @orthocresol <nod>, as long as it's just acidifying the matrix, it should probably work ok.